# Wordpress: next page on pagination always return to index.php

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I tried to add a simple pagination to my custom page by using WP_Query. However, after I click on the next page link, it will always go to index.php (since I still don't have 404.php in my theme)

This my code for my custom page that include with pagination

```
  <?php 
    $temp = $wp_query; 
    $wp_query = null; 
    $wp_query = new WP_Query(); 
    $wp_query->query('showposts=2&cat=2'.'&paged='.$paged); 

    while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); 
  ?>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 article-list" data-sr='enter bottom, move 50px, over 0.5s'>
      <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><p class="article-link-img"><?php the_post_thumbnail('small-thumbnail'); ?></p>
      <p class="article-link-title"><?php the_title(); ?></p></a>
    </div>

  <?php endwhile; ?>
  <nav>
    <?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Newer') ?>
    <?php next_posts_link('Older &raquo;') ?>
  </nav>
  <?php 
    $wp_query = null; 
    $wp_query = $temp;  // Reset
  ?>
```

and this is the code in my index.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="container index-section">
  <section>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
          <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>
        <?php endwhile; else: ?>
          <h1 class="index-error-message"><?php _e('Sorry, this post does not exist.'); ?></h1>
          <h2 class="single-article-popular-title">Popular Articles</h2>
            <?php 
              $topBlogs = new WP_Query('orderby=rand&cat=3&posts_per_page=4');

              if ($topBlogs -> have_posts() ) : 
                while ($topBlogs -> have_posts() ) : $topBlogs -> the_post(); ?>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 single-article-popular-list">
                  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><p><?php the_post_thumbnail('small-thumbnail'); ?></p>
                  <p class="single-article-popular-link-title"><?php the_title(); ?></p></a>
                </div>
              <?php endwhile; else: ?>
                <h3>No content found</h3>
              <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I was trying to figured it out what is the problem, but still don't have the solution. I also have tried to use WP_PageNAVi plugin, but still have the same result.

This is the full code for my custom page

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <div class="article-featured">
      <div class="container">
        <section>
          <div class="row">
            <?php 
              $featuredBlogs = new WP_Query('cat=4&posts_per_page=1');

              if ($featuredBlogs -> have_posts() ) : while ($featuredBlogs -> have_posts() ) : $featuredBlogs -> the_post(); ?>
                <div class="col-md-12 article-featured-descr">
                  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><p class="article-featured-descr-text" data-sr='enter bottom, move 50px, over 0.5s'>Featured article</p>
                  <h1 data-sr='enter bottom, move 50px, wait 0.3s, over 0.5s'><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                  <img src="/ecteciant/wp-content/themes/ecteciant/files/images/article/no-article.png" alt="no article" data-sr='enter bottom, move 50px, wait 0.6s, over 0.5s'></a>
                </div>
              <?php endwhile; else: ?>
                <div class="col-md-12 article-featured-descr">
                  <p class="article-featured-descr-text" data-sr='enter bottom, move 50px, over 0.5s'>No featured article found</p>
                  <img src="/ecteciant/wp-content/themes/ecteciant/files/images/article/no-article.png" alt="no article" data-sr='enter bottom, move 50px, wait 0.3s, over 0.5s'>
                </div>
              <?php endif; ?>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="container">
      <section>
        <div class="row">
          <?php 
            $temp = $wp_query; 
            $wp_query = null; 
            $wp_query = new WP_Query(); 
            $wp_query->query('showposts=2&cat=2'.'&paged='.$paged); 

            while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); 
          ?>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 article-list" data-sr='enter bottom, move 50px, over 0.5s'>
              <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><p class="article-link-img"><?php the_post_thumbnail('small-thumbnail'); ?></p>
              <p class="article-link-title"><?php the_title(); ?></p></a>
            </div>

          <?php endwhile; ?>
          <nav>
            <?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Newer') ?>
            <?php next_posts_link('Older &raquo;') ?>
          </nav>
          <?php 
            $wp_query = null; 
            $wp_query = $temp;  // Reset
          ?>

          <div class="col-md-12 article-not-found">
            <img src="/ecteciant/wp-content/themes/ecteciant/files/images/article/submit-article.png" alt="submit article" data-sr='enter bottom, move 50px, over 0.5s'>
            <p data-sr='enter bottom, move 50px, wait 0.3s, over 0.5s'>What do you think about <b>"A"</b>? How about <b>"B"</b>?<br/>Send your thoughts to <a href="mailto:article@ecteciant.com?Subject=New%20Article%20Inquiry">article@ecteciant.com</a>, we accept from <b>A to Z.</b> Our team will review your submission.<br/>Stand a chance to be <b>FEATURED</b> in our page.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/share_button.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fbudilokawijaya.com&layout=button_count&mobile_iframe=true&width=86&height=20&appId" width="86" height="20" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>

        <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?button_hashtag=ecteciantID" class="twitter-hashtag-button" data-related="budi_czras,ecteciantID" data-url="http://ecteciant.com">Tweet #ecteciantID</a>-->
      </section>
    </div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I just found an answer from another forum that solved this problem.

By modifying the admin in Reading to Blog pages show at most = 1, it solved the issue. But not sure why this solved the issue and I also don't know if there is any drawback by doing this.

At least this solved the problem.

If anyone know a better solutions, please post your solutions.

Comment: This worked for me, if anyone is wondering, where is that particular setting, open the admin menu and go to *settings* -> *reading*.